# Powershell environment variable

Tags: powershell, variables, environment

In a Powershell script (.ps1)
Launched from the command line of a console (cmd.exe)

How can set and environment variable in the console,
so that when the Powershell script ends processing,
and exits to the console where was invoked... 
the environment variable exists,
and can be read by a batch file,
or viewed with the SET command ?

do not want to set a 'Machine' or a 'User' variable...
only a console process variable...
the same variable you get if you use SET in the console

Answer (score 3):

To run a PowerShell script from `cmd.exe` invariably requires a (`powershell.exe` / `pwsh.exe`) *child process*, and **child processes fundamentally *cannot* set environment variables for their *parent* process**<sup>[1]</sup>.

Your best bet is to **have your `*.ps1` file *output* the *name and value* of the desired environment variable and then have the calling `cmd.exe` process create it**, based on that output.

**Security note**: Blindly defining environment variables based on the name-value pairs output by another command (a `*.ps1` script, in your case) should only be done if you *trust* that command not to output malicious definitions.

Here's a **simple example** (run directly from an interactive `cmd.exe` session):

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1,*" %v in ('powershell.exe -c "'FOO=bar'"') do @set "%v=%w"
```

The above defines environment variable `%FOO%` with value `bar`, based on the PowerShell command outputting the literal name-value pair `FOO=bar`.
Verify with `echo %FOO%`.

To extend this approach to **defining *multiple* environment variables**, make the command output each definition on its own line (which in PowerShell you can achieve by outputting an *array* of strings):

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1,*" %v in ('powershell.exe -c "'FOO=bar', 'BAZ=bam'"') do @set "%v=%w"
```

The above additionally defines `%BAZ%` with value `bam`.

---

To make this more convenient, **I suggest creating a *wrapper batch file* (`*.cmd`) that performs the above**:

- Note that you'll have to use `%%v` and `%%w` instead of `%v` and `%w` there.
- Instead of `-c` (for `-Command`) with the demo command, use `-File` with the path to your `*.ps1` file to invoke it.

  - Also consider use of `-NoProfile` as well, to bypass loading of your PowerShell environment's `$PROFILE` file, which not only slows things down, but may pollute your command's output.

---

<sup>[1] As [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) points out, child processes inherit *copies* of the parent process' environment variables. Modifications of these copies are never seen by the parent. A child process is fundamentally unable to modify its *parent's* environment, which is a restriction at the *OS* level - for good reasons: Modifying a running process' environment by an arbitrary (child) process would be a serious security concern.</sup>

Comment: @ZEE: LotPings is correct: this restriction is an OS-level restriction (not just on Windows), and it exists for good reasons - see the footnote I've added to the answer. I've also amended the solution to output not just the value but also the _name_ of the environment variable(s) to define.

Comment: Understable... but as this is a MS thing... and the CMD/BATCH console is yet ubiquitous... and there are lots os Powershell scripts invoked fom the CMD.exe command line...  I wish they had tought about this... and come out with a solution... ;-)

Comment: @ZEE: If you need a simple solution, stick with a given shell: with cmd.exe, use a batch file to set the environment variables; with PowerShell, use a `*.ps1` file; in both cases, the batch file / script runs _in-process_. Calling PowerShell from cmd.exe generally works, just not in your specific scenario, by design, as explained. Under the circumstance, the solution in this answer (or a variation thereof) is your best bet.